How do I create a list for modelsummary() from models created using map()
I am often fitting models for more than one dependent variable in this way. It lets me get the coefficients quickly for plotting. But then I have a hard time passing these results to modelsummary() to print the full regression tables.
library(tidyverse)
library(modelsummary)
mtcars %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=c(mpg, hp)) %>% 
  nest(-name) %>% 
  mutate(., model1=map(data, ~lm(value~disp, data=.)), 
         model2=map(data, ~lm(value~disp+cyl, data=.)), 
         model3=map(data, ~lm(value~disp*cyl, data=.))) %>% 
mutate(across(model1:model3, ~map(., tidy), .names="{col}_tidied")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(model1_tidied:model3_tidied,names_to = "Model_Name", values_to=c("Results")) %>% 
  unnest(Results)->models

Can this be done quickly and efficiently?
Part of the problem is that the items in each  list column (model1, model2, etc.) are themselves lists.
glimpse(models)

This works, but I feel like there has to be a way to make this go more quickly.
modelsummary(list(models$model1[[1]], models$model2[[1]], models$model3[[1]]))


This serves my purpose pretty well:
# start with object storing everything
models %>% 
#Pick the row of the dependent variable that you want
  slice(1) %>% 
#SElect only the columns containing the unnested models
  select(3:5) %>% 
#Map over each picking out only the list item in the list column
  map(., ~.[[1]]) %>% 
#pass to modelsummary and modify to your heart's content.
  modelsummary()


